# Compatibilidad de diferentes pantallas en Scene Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, interfaz-gráfica, programación-funcional, scenebuilder

Me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto en Scene Builder. La cuestión es la siguiente: El proyecto se está realizando entre Eclipse y Scene Builder. En medio del desarrollo con más personas nos encontramos con un problema. En Scene Builder le colocamos un tamaño a la ventana, pero al momento de correr el proyecto en eclipse la ventana tiene un tamaño diferente (en mi caso menor), para otras puede ser mayor o incluso menor. ¿Qué debo hacer para que el tamaño sea igual para todas las pantallas?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si no pones un [ejemplo concreto y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) va a ser difícil poder ayudarte. Por otra parte lo que comentas no debería ocurrir.

Comment: En este caso le colocó un tamaño 1530 en width y 790 en height desde scene builder. Lo que muestra casi el máximo de tamaño desde scene builder, pero corriendolo desde eclipse se muestra casi a la mitad. Y a otra persona se le sale de la pantalla

Comment: Lee lo que te compartí sobre cómo incluir un ejemplo mínimo y verificable. Lo que me estás diciendo es imposible de analizar.